# Getting fired for cause?

Tags: references, united-states, termination

I have recently been in a fight with the management team of my company. After that incident, the company accussed me of stealing proprietary information, and made me take a few paid days off while they "investigate" the issue. They are calling me in and have scheduled a meeting between myself, the management team, and the legal council. In the meantime they have slandered my character among my co-workers while the "investigation", which is a witch-hunt according to my co-workers, is still on-going.

I am 100% sure they can't find any evidence of wrongdoing, but I am also sure I don't want to stay at this company. However, I want to leave in a "clean" way. I don't want to have a record that I was fired for cause.

My questions are

1. If they insist that I am fired for cause, what can I do, and how do I fight for myself?
2. Will the fact that I was fired for cause be visible to my future employers?
3. What kind of legal paperwork should I expect, if I am terminated? Just to get an idea so I know what I should expect. Do I get a different set of paperwork if I resign?

My company is in New York State, United States.

Comment: Bring a lawyer to the meeting

Comment: What country? Your legal protections are based on national laws.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep my company is in New York State

Comment: What do you mean with record? It is not like your new employer sees the HR file? And IFF they were asked for reference they may slip a comment anyway (i don't know your laws, in some countries it is AFAIK prohibited to say anything else but yes, worked here…)

Comment: @Chad I'd disagree. Sure some legal council is recommended, but I think The Workplace can provide answers to #2 and #3, and should be able to provide a decent place to start for #1.

Comment: @CodeNoob, if I were you, I'd leave the company only after the investigation is over and they hopefully can't accuse you of anything. Also, if you say your coworkers call this a witch-hunt, see if they can give you recommendations, like in LinkedIn.

Comment: Evidence of wrongdoing can be faked.

Comment: I presume that you are not a member of a union, and thus do not have a union representative to talk to? Is there any equivalent to the UK's [CAB](http://www.adviceguide.org.uk/) in the US?

Comment: @MarkBooth - The author works in New York, which has "at will employment" in other words, neither party as an obligation to one other ( beyond the terms they agree to ). This means its unlikely the author is in an industry where there would even be a union created.  It is very hard to create a union, if it does not already exist, this means he is likely working for a private company.

Comment: @Ramhound - I understand what [at will employment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment) is, hence my presumption, but that doesn't preclude the possibility that he *might* have an explicit contract and could even be working in a unionised environment, so it is better to check rather than to [assume](http://assume.urbanup.com/304172).

Comment: @MarkBooth - I agree about assuming but it seems that is the minority opinion here some times.

Comment: "I am 100% sure they can't find any evidence of wrongdoing" makes me think you're guilty.

Answer (score 15):

> If they insist that I am fired for cause, what can I do, and how do I
>   fight for me?

You get a good lawyer who specializes in employment law.  Try to find one who has worked on the other side(for big businesses).  This is probably going to cost you money but getting a lawyer now will probably save you in the end.  If you are in the right then hopefully you can end up with a settlement that will cover your costs.  If you do not get one now and this goes forward(I would assume it will) your costs will go up and your chance of recovery will go down.

> Is the fired for cause visible to my future employers?

That will depend on the policies of your employer.  Most companies in the US are willing to confirm your employment and if you are eligible for rehire.  Some companies are willing to go further.  I know of no law that prohibits an employer from sharing its opinion of you.

> What kind of legal paperwork do I usually get, if I am terminated?
>   Just to get an idea so I know what I should expect. Do I get a
>   different set of paperwork if I resign?

Unless you get sued your company will provide you with as little documentation as it can get away with.  This information can be used against it so I would expect that you will only get information if they sue you.  And they will drag their feet in producing anything more than the bare minimum of documentation to support it.  This is why you need a lawyer.  The lawyer will know what documents you will be entitled to and can ask the important questions up front before it gets to the courts.  Hopefully preempting any proceedings against you and building a case for recovery for you.

In the law it is often not the truth that matters but how the evidence can be presented.  You can be right and still lose big.  You need a lawyer and you need one now.

Comment: Good stuff.  I'd add to it that in larger companies, there is also often a third party monitored conflict resolution process.  It's usually a tiered process (not unlike tech support) where you can bring your cause and have mediation handled by an impartial third party.  When this service exists, it may be something you want to try in parellel with or before you call the lawyer as the process is free, but the lawyer costs you money.  The lawyer, however, is fully on your side, so may be more of an advocate.

Comment: " I know of no law that prohibits an employer from sharing its opinion of you."  Giving any opinion or "going farther" as you put it is a VERY rare practice because if you give a glowing recommendation, and the person ends up being terrible, you can be sued by the other company.  If you instead trash an ex employee, or really say anything at all and they do not get the job, then they can sue you for damaging their reputation/slander/causing them to lose a job opportunity.  It's sad, but that's the state of the world.

Comment: Thanks Chad. Regarding your second point, under what circumstance would my future employer call my current company? They might ask for references, but I have plenty of co-workers that love me and would be happy to serve as my reference. Why would they call my current employer?

Comment: Companies look to your performance in the past with other companies as an indication of expectation for future performance.  So even if you give your coworkers by name they may want to talk with the company to verify.  Sometimes in a background check they will need to get an official response from your employer.

Comment: @acolyte - There is no law that prohibits it though.  I did not say they would or would not give a reference.  In either case the burden is on the claimant to prove damages so that is a minor concern for the exceptional circumstance.

Comment: @Chad fair enough, my apologies.

Comment: @CodeNoob See my related answer to a similar question... http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2223/70

Comment: @CodeNoob Typical background checks basically ask a company if X employee worked their from Y to Z dates, and if they were dismissed for a reason. Firing for an explicit reason is a legal minefield, so most of the time, a company will not give a reason unless their legal team is 125% certain that **you** would not have a case if you were to sue them.  Your manager may hold a grudge, but legal teams follow strict guidelines and would not allow you to be officially fired with reason unless they were sure they would win.  Lawyer up bud because it sounds like you really screwed up.

Comment: Another reason to get a lawyer is that being fired means they can deny you unemployment. A lawyer might negotiate with them to agree to lay you off instead to avoid an expensive lawsuit.

Comment: @HLGEM This is the single best response thus far, and is probably the BEST reason to get a lawyer involved as soon as possible.

Comment: @HLGEM - You could be eligible for unemployment even if you were fired.  In fact it is harder to prove cause for unemployment than you would think.  We had someone get arrested for theft from the cash register collecting unemployment even though they went to jail.  On top of that chances are the lawyer will cost more than you would get in unemployment  for several months.

Comment: BTW not being eligible for rehire is effectively HR Speak for we do not recommend you hire said person.

Comment: @Chad, that's true, but the person without the legal representation is easier to convince that they are not eligible for unemployment or less likely to fight an initial decision against them. Plus the company may be more willing to give in on fighting the unemployment compensation if they know he is lawyered up.

Comment: @Hlgem - Completely agree.  Which is why my first, second and third points all said get a lawyer.

Comment: Ill add one thing. In New York your employer is not required to provide you with the termination document. As a matter of fact, my company policy is to refuse any requests of the termination document or accompanying documents.

Comment: Out of curiosity how does it make sense to have 'fired for cause' in a place with 'employment at will'. I thought the whole point of employment at will is you could get fired at any time for any reason.

Comment: @dashofpepper - Being fired for cause eliminates some protections a person might other wise have, like unemployment, but in the eyes of the court when you file a suit after being fired it can appear to be nothing more than sour grapes.  In a he said she said case that can often tip the balance in favor of the employer (which already has the deck stacked in their favor usually)

Answer (score 12):

If you primary concern is that the current employer will attempt in some way to blacken your reputation then you need to bring in a lawyer now.

In my experience -- *as someone with an MS in Human Resources* -- HR representatives are likely to negotiate more favorably for you if you have a lawyer because they are terrified of an employee with a lawyer. A [principal](http://humanresources.about.com/od/discrimination/qt/prevent-employment-discrimination.htm) [purpose](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGcQFjAC&url=http://hrdailyadvisor.blr.com/archive/2008/02/25/Preventing_Lawsuits_Seven_Stupid_Things_Supervisors_Say.aspx&ei=p8gjUKCsA6Ka2gXAoYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNHcPfKRFyK4M_ml4qud9P9AQLeY9w&sig2=fKhvgadTCCpuADKrVX0Kpw) [of HR](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGkQFjAD&url=http://blogs.findlaw.com/in_house/2012/08/5-strategies-to-prevent-ex-employee-lawsuits.html?=features&ei=p8gjUKCsA6Ka2gXAoYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNH_MMvD6SXgKWPplHCMxmBZFOfOBw&sig2=kosuMJRS6i1LNr3zekNlhw) [is to](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CGsQFjAE&url=http://www.adssglobal.net/starinfo/abra/q208/ads_q208_abra.pdf&ei=p8gjUKCsA6Ka2gXAoYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNFhEynf31odL3YlNwex2Xc8k4_VbQ&sig2=E8LzRxEeize5-2XQnyat8Q) [prevent](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CHEQFjAG&url=http://proactivelawsuitprevention.blogspot.com/2010/09/webinar-invitation.html&ei=p8gjUKCsA6Ka2gXAoYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNEG-SD-02tRmFmnU2duai98eJZj8g&sig2=5dvtZ0Y7UjFc-TTRioeGoA) [lawsuits](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHYQFjAJ&url=http://www.hrmreport.com/article/Dont-Just-Do-It/&ei=p8gjUKCsA6Ka2gXAoYC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNF4dCWQnHvmS_i2WDigtNGuDlzKQw&sig2=WuXh9C61PtzzRgEdE6u3tw).

Spend a thousand dollars now, bring in a lawyer to negotiate a written agreement concerning your departure from the present position.  This will be much cheaper than waiting until you've been fired and later found out that this employer is hurting you professionally.

If unemployment insurance is a possibility issue speak to whichever state agency handles unemployment compensation for New York.

States administer these programs. In Texas the Workforce Commission has a good record of standing up to employers who try and treat terminated employees unfairly.